# The name for the submodule/subobject which splits.

Tags: commutative-algebra, category-theory, notation, modules

The below problem can be refolmulated into language of category theory, but I stick to algebra.

Let's say that we have a commutative ring $R,$ a $R$-module $M$ and a submodule $S$ of $M.$ Assume that except natural embedding $\iota:S\hookrightarrow  M$ we have a second $R$-linear map $\pi:M\to S$ such that $\pi\circ\iota = id_M.$

> **Question.** Does such $S$ have some name?

I would like to call it "splitting submodule" or "submodule which splits $M$". However I am not sure whether it would be correct.

Comment: "Direct summand"? (By the splitting lemma)

Comment: That was my first reaction too. I don't see any difference between this and a "direct summand."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In an abelian category, by the splitting lemma, $S$ is just a direct summand of $M.$

In a general (not necessarily abelian) category, $S$ is a [retract](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/retract) of $M$, and may not be a direct summand in general.